# Android: Marking mTabHost as an active Tab Host

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabview

I created my own style tab host using separate layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/tabsLayout"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:paddingTop="10dp"
                  android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabs_image"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabs_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And I am using this method to add a tab host

```
private static View createTabView(final Context context, final Drawable image, final String text) {
    View tab_view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_bg, null);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) tab_view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_image);
    img.setImageDrawable(image);
    TextView txt_text = (TextView) tab_view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_tv);
    txt_text.setText(text);
    return tab_view;
}
```

By adding tab host, I already created tabview that consist of several tabhost. This is how I add my mTabHost

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_data_visualization), "Gender")), FragmentChartGender.class, null);
```

My question is, how can I create **different style for an active tabhost**? Because my tab host doesn't show its different wether it's active or not, see [mine](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwRkP0GWWGK-S1VfZkZvTXo1M3M). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: by Different styles  what do you mean ? can you elaborate

Comment: I am sorry. I just wanna make some different title tabhost if it is active. Mine doesn't show its active tab. Just same style, all of them. Look at mine [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRkP0GWWGK-S1VfZkZvTXo1M3M/view?usp=sharing). I want something like [this](http://news.qooxdoo.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/android-tabs.png)

Comment: try using mTabHost.setCurrentTab (indexOfTab); provide the index of tab that you want it to be active ,and also try this [link](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)